# running button commands on startup

Tags: python, button, tkinter, command, startup

I'm currently working on a program to scan a folder, find all the .exe files and place them in a list ready to run.

So far, I have managed to get the list, create the buttons, but not then run the program itself. Instead it is running the programs upon opening running the python code.

```
import os
import Tkinter

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def run(exe):
    os.system(exe)

exes = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'./'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.exe'):
            exes.append(file)

def dispgames(exes):
    exes = exes[:-4]
    return exes

def runit(game):
    os.system(game)

#print(exes)
#print(dispgames(exes))


def radioCreate(typeArray):
    for t in typeArray:
        b = Tkinter.Button(top, text = dispgames(t), command=runit(t))
        b.pack()

radioCreate(exes)

Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Display").pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format all your code, not the first line.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to use the code snippet function on here and got a little confused. I have sorted it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

`command` expects function name - it means without `()` and arguments.

You can use `lambda` to do this

```
command=lambda:runit(t)
```

but you create it in `for` loop so there can be problem with `t`.

`lambda` use reference to `t` , not value copied from `t` - so all `lambda` created in loop will use the same value - last value assigned to `t`.

But you can copy value from `t` to other variable in `lambda`

```
command=lambda x=t:runit(x)
```

-

`command=runit(t)` means "run function `runit(t)` and result assign to `command`". Sometimes it can be usefull.

-

BTW: in Tkinter `bind()` and `after()` also expect function name.

Comment: Thank you. this helped a little. I've tried this with 2 programs in the folder "test1.exe" and "test2.exe". when I click the button for test1.exe it's runing test2.exe, but the button for test2.exe works as it should.

Comment: if you use `lambda:runit(t)` in `for` loop then all lambda use the same value - because they use reference to the same place in memory which has last value assigned to `t` (`test2.exe`). if you use `lambda x=t:runit(x)` then `x=t` will copy value from `t` and every lambda has different value in `x`.